# Change values in a multidimension Scala array

Tags: scala

I'm pretty new in Scala and trying to change the values in a multi dimension Array in the *Scala way* if there is such thing :)

Let's see the problem:

```
val table = Array.fill(5, 5){1}
```

and I'm trying to change every 1 to 5

```
for (i <- 0 until table.length) {
  for (j <- 0 until table(i).length) {
    table(i)(j) = 5
  }
}
```

But I think there will be some other (more functional way) to do the same thing.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm a bit confused why you had to initialize table to have 1s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
val table = List.fill(5, 5){1}
val all5 = table.map(_.map(_ => 5))
```

Comment: That produces a copy of the table with all 5s, rather than changing the original. That may or may not be what the OP wanted.

Comment: OP said functional, which is easier to reason about when it's immutable.

Comment: As I said, may or may not be what he wants. Let's see.

Comment: Thank you, it's perfectly fine for me. I think it's nicer to create a new table and don't change the input parameter. Clearly I have to learn more scala because it looks weird for my Java-trained eyes :)